# Repeating a Region in an HTML Page

Tags: php, repeat

i have been trying to learn PHP Repeat Region... i have searched google but came across very complicated code samples, [e.g](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Code/Nested-repeat-region/) & [e.g](http://www.bigresource.com/PHP-repeat-region-checkboxes-p7aK63pJ.html), i would like if somebody be kind enough to provide a simple code sample... like what i am doing is

i have a query which gets results and makes a list with result

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT names,age,nic FROM t_able WHERE state='1'");

<ul>
    // The the targeted repeat region starts here
    <li> 
    //my data  
    </li>
    // The target repeat region ends here
</ul>
```

i know i can do this with a loop but why bother when repeat region functionality is there...why not learn...

p.s. this question is to make the learning simple and AS it is a programming question don't vote down :) or vote to close it ;p

Comment: Uhm, I don't know where you see the magic here. You don't need anything nested here (in this case). A "repeat region" is basically what you already know: A loop which iterates over an array of data..

Comment: whats this <?php do { ?><p><?php echo $row_newsinfo['newstitle']; ?></p>

Comment: you are missing the while() part in that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that is not enough? I dont think there is simpler without a framework and viewhelpers.

```
<?php
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT names,age,nic FROM t_able WHERE state='1'");
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){ ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo $array['names']; ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple loop, which one usually learns quite early on in programming. You may have heard some strange terminology that's just making this more complex than it needs to be.

```
// Repeat as long as there is a preceding row
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    echo "<li>";
    echo "Names: " . $row["names"]; // Add other data
    echo "</li>";
}
```